Why are decorators necessary as opposed to nesting functions?
I'm having a hard time understanding the purpose of decorators and I think it's because of the examples for use cases I've been given. I'm a noob on day 55 of a python course and the example I was given was for timing.
Suppose I have the functions fast_function() and slow_function() and I want to time their execution. The course I'm taking suggests using decorators. But it seems simpler to create a function like
def time(function):
    begin=time.time()
    function()
    end=time.time()
    return end-begin


They aren't necessary.  It's just two ways of writing the same thing.  All that a decorator does is wrap a function around another function.  It's just a more concise way of writing that.  In 30 years of Python, I think I've only written 1 decorator myself.  I wouldn't worry about it.

Decorators are mostly semantic sugar for a reusable function wrapper, which can reduce redundant code and their names should be self-documenting do the purpose is clearm. A couple examples I've written: 1) persistent function cache, which loads from disk on program start and saves on program exit 2) wrapper for flask app routes to check if user is logged in and redirect to login page if they aren't.

Take a look at Why do we need wrapper function in decorators? (Spoiler: we don't)

Yes, you could write a timer function around function X to time it.  Then, when you want to time function Y instead ... another timer function is called for.  Using decorators is just a handy way to have a toolbox of reusable utility functions.  If you instead had some specific requirements for timing function X and another set of requirements for timing function Y, then you would gain little from writing 2 different, single-use, decorators.  If instead you are saying... "but I could just pass in the function..." You could but you'd have to take into account its call arguments.

The corresponding decorator would not be very different from what you describe.

That is very similar to a decorator:

A function returning another function, usually applied as a function transformation using the @wrapper syntax.

The difference is with a decorator, a new function is returned, and that new, transformed function can be called multiple times without the wrapping being obvious to the caller. With your way, to wrap the code, the caller would need to involve a call to time each time.
